# jQuery .hover() fires on old element after hovering on new one

Tags: jquery, hover, slide, effects

I Have a div with two labels nested in it which are links to other pages and are one next to the other.

I am applying a slide in effect to a third div which is placed under the labels on hovering.

The problem I'm encountering is that the effect works properly if I hover on one of the labels, then remove the mouse from it but not moving into the next label.

If I move from a label to the other directly the slide in effect of the hidden div occurs on the first label hovered and not the current one.

HTML:

```
<div class="top">
<label class="head left" id="home">Welcome - <?php echo $_SESSION['description'] . " (" . $_SESSION['lid'] . ")"; ?>
</label>
<label id="logout" class="head right">Logout</label>
```

jQuery Code:

```
// Slide in effect for hover on class=head labels
        $("#home, #logout").hover(function () {
            // Set width to hovering element width:
            $(".labelunderscore").css("width", $(this).width() + 20);
            // Set position on labelunderscore to current element left value
            $(".labelunderscore").css("left", $(this).offset().left);
            // Check where are we hovering. Left side slide from left right from right
            if ($(this).offset().left > $(window).width()/2) {
                // We are on the right side
                $('.labelunderscore').show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 200);
            } else {
                // Left side
                $('.labelunderscore').show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 200);
            }
        }).mouseout(function () {
            $('.labelunderscore').hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 200);
        })
```

Comment: Can you provide your home and logout html content?

Comment: You are using `in/out` hover method syntax, surely not what you expect. I guess you are confusing this method with `mouseover()` one  https://api.jquery.com/hover/  **||**  https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

Comment: Hi. Irvin I'm only looking for the effect. The pages are not ready and in any case they would be handled through the .click() function

Comment: Using two handlers hover is working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/rto2hz5k/

Comment: Hi. Modified the fiddle to place the labels next to each other. If you hover on the first one the slide the mouse right the effect will appear again on the first one. This is my problem. I have added a border to distinguish the 2 labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. The problem was the `labelunderscore` div that was created in the page. This "confuses" the jquery library as whilst it applying the slide in effect, it has to apply the slide out effect **on the same div**.

The problem has been sorted by creating the `labelunderscore` div in the function at runtime and assigning it a unique id based on the id of the hovered element. Code as follows:

```
// Slide in effect for hover on class=head labels
        $(".head").hover(function () {
            //alert($(this).attr('id'))
            $('#main').append('<div id="labelunderscore_' + $(this).attr("id") + '" class="labelunderscore"></div>');
            // Set width to hovering element width:
            $('#labelunderscore_' + $(this).attr("id")).css("width", $(this).width() + 20);
            // Set position on labelunderscore to current element left value
            $('#labelunderscore_' + $(this).attr("id")).css("left", $(this).offset().left);
            // Check where are we hovering. Left side slide from left right from right
            if ($(this).offset().left > $(window).width()/2) {
                // We are on the right side
                $('#labelunderscore_' + $(this).attr("id")).show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 200);
            } else {
                // Left side
                $('#labelunderscore_' + $(this).attr("id") ).show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 200);
            }
        }, function () {
            $('#labelunderscore_' + $(this).attr("id")).hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 200);
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Just listen for hover on the parent of the labels, so they are not treated as two separate elements for mousein/out:

e.g.

```
$(".top").hover(function () {
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/rto2hz5k/6/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Found the problem. It was the sliding div. Basically the error was using the same `labelunderscore` div. This was probably confusing jQuery as whilst applying the hide effect on on label it had to apply the show effect on the other but on the same div element! Problem has been solved by creating the div dynamically and assigning it a uniuqe id.

Comment: @Fabrizio Mazzoni: That is a different problem to the one you described. Please post your solution as answer.

Comment: OK. Shall I add it to the question?

Comment: @Fabrizio Mazzoni: If it answers your question, add it as an answer.